# extrapolation data

Tags: fitting

I need help to extrapolate these data:

```
θ = {20.7, 28.62, 32.04};
ω = {5, 6, 7};
```

using this equation:

θ(ω)=θ(ω⟶∞)+ c /ω^n  to know what the values of c and n

I found a result using the below plot:

```
ListLinePlot[
    Transpose[{ω^-4,#}]&/@{θ},
    FrameLabel->{"1/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ω\), \(4\)]\)","θ"},
    Axes->True,
    Frame->True,
    AxesStyle->Directive[{Bold,25},{Black,25}],
    BaseStyle->{FontWeight->Bold,FontSize->14},
    PlotRange->All,
    PlotMarkers->{"◆",18}
]
```

But my problem how to obtain the fits using the extrapolation for the above equation using Mathematica.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope your statistics class mentioned that fitting a curve with 3 parameters and 3 data points is crazy and then expecting to be able to extrapolate (let alone interpolate) when there is by definition a perfect fit (i.e., no ability to estimate error) is even crazier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple model, you don't need explicit `NonlinearModelFit` since you can just use the trasformed predictors in `LinearModelFit` as follows to achieve the desired fit:

```
ClearAll[fittedFunction];
fittedFunction=LinearModelFit[Transpose@{ω,θ},{1,x^-4},x]["Function"];
```

Now you can call this function outside your existing domain for extrapolation:

```
fittedFunction[4]
```

> -1.39249

```
fittedFunction[8]
```

> 33.6831

you can see fit errors:

```
θ-fittedFunction[ω]
```

> {0.00330966, -0.0110303, 0.00772069}

---

To just do an extrapolation based on existing edge gradients without using least square technique, just use linear interpolation as follows:

```
ClearAll[fittedFunction];
fittedFunction=With[{
    interpolatedFunction=Interpolation[Transpose@{ω^-4,θ},InterpolationOrder->1]
},
    Function[ω,Quiet@interpolatedFunction[ω^-4],Listable]
];
```

Now you can call this function (like before) outside your existing domain for extrapolation:

```
fittedFunction[4]
```

> -1.34926

```
fittedFunction[8]
```

> 33.6999

you can see fit errors are zeros since existing gradients are used:

```
θ-fittedFunction[ω]
```

> {0., 0., 0.}

Comment: Thanks a lot! suppose we don't know what is the value of n, is there a way to know the values of n and c using the extrapolation?

Comment: If you want the `n` to be determined by the model as well then the situation is non-linear than you can use the `NonlinearModelFit[Transpose@{ω,θ},β0+c/x^n,{β0,c,n},x]` suggested in the other answer. But since you don't have enough data to allow the degrees of freedom needed for another parameter it won't work! You need at least 4 points.

Comment: another option is to just run `model=LinearModelFit[Transpose@{ω,θ},{1,x^-n},x]` for different values of `n` and look at the significance of the `x^-n` term in the `model["ParameterTable"]` and overall variance explainability of the model using `model["RSquared"]`.

Comment: Note the lack of degrees of freedom can be seen in the `LinearModelFit` as well if you introduce another parameter (coefficient) to be estimated in the model. Since you have insufficient data to allow an additional degree of freedom for the new term, it results in a perfect fit. For example, `model=LinearModelFit[Transpose@{ω,θ},{1,1/x,1/x^4},x]` will have an `model["RSquared"]==1` i.e. perfect fit with no variance unexplained.

Comment: Thank you again! your comments are so useful.

Answer (score 1):

Given `n==4` you might try

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[ωθ, θ0 + c/ω^4 , {θ0, c, n}, ω]
Normal[fit]
(*36.0214 - 9577.97/ω^4*)
```

This approach might be extended to although fit `n` (more data necessary)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!